# Trouble with making enviroments instead of sections

Tags: environments

I am trying to find a way to create an environment or multiple environments so I can create something like what I have here, but to automatically number the parts and print the text, eg step 1..... diagram 1..... step 2..... diagram 2...... without having to type it all in, and use figures etc. Is this possible or am I just wasting my and your time?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}


\newcommand{\AB}{0.7}   % A  and B added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\C}{1.0}    % C added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\Asize}{0.25}   % Angle added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\newcommand{\mylipsum}{just dummy text}
\newcommand{\mylipsums}{Step 1}

% Standard packages
\usepackage{
float, 
graphicx
}

% Set page margins
\usepackage[top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in, left=1.0in, right=1.0in]{geometry}

\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0pt}

% Set nice page headers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% Paragraph style
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}


% Proposition environment
\newenvironment{proposition}
{\begin{center}\em}
{\end{center}}

%Diagram enviroment    
\newenvironment{diagram}
{\begin{center}\vspace*{10pt}\begin{tikzpicture}}
{\end{tikzpicture}\vspace*{-5pt}\end{center}}
 
 
\setcounter{chapter}{-1}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
{0pt}{0pt}{30pt}

\titleformat{\section}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{-20pt}{\Large}
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{0pt}{10pt}


\begin{document}

\chapter{example}

\section{some text and diagrams}
    \begin{proposition}
        \mylipsum
    \end{proposition}

    \begin{diagram}
    \tkzDefPoints{-\AB/0/A,\AB/0/B,0/\C/C}

    \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=green,opacity=0.5](A,B,C)
    
    \tkzLabelPoints[left](A)
    \tkzLabelPoints[right](B)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
          
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,C)
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](B,C)
 
       \end{diagram}
    
 \mylipsums\\
 \mylipsum

 \begin{diagram}
 \tkzDefPoints{-\AB/0/A,\AB/0/B,0/\C/C}

    \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=green,opacity=0.5](A,B,C)
    
    \tkzLabelPoints[left](A)
    \tkzLabelPoints[right](B)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
          
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=||](A,C)
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=||](B,C)
\end{diagram}

\mylipsums\\
 \mylipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: See \newcounter, \stepcoutner and \refstepcounter.  Usually one uses \the... (as in \thepage) to print the counter value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
\newcounter{CountStep}
\newenvironment{diagram}
{\begin{center}\vspace*{10pt}\begin{tikzpicture}}
        {\end{tikzpicture}\vspace*{-5pt}\par\stepcounter{CountStep} Step=~\theCountStep\end{center}}
```

Or

```
\newcounter{CountStep}
\newcounter{CountDiag}
\newenvironment{diagram}
{\begin{center}\stepcounter{CountStep}\stepcounter{CountDiag}\vspace*{10pt} Step~\theCountStep\par\begin{tikzpicture}}
        {\end{tikzpicture}\vspace*{-5pt}\par Diagram~\theCountDiag
    \end{center}}
```

[image: b]